# How to manage Android devices using Android Management API?

Tags: android, android-management-api

How can I create a system to enroll devices with minimal steps and publish a private app for enrolled devices using Google Cloud project and Android Management API? Also, is there a dashboard available to view all the enrolled devices and perform other tasks like sending commands and policies? Additionally, which account do I need to publish private apps and manage enrolled devices, a Google Play developer account or a Google Admin Console account?

Answer (score 0):

To enroll devices and publish private apps using the Android Management API, refer to the [Android Management API Quickstart Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb). This guide will walk you through the process of enrolling an enterprise, creating policies for app distribution and device management, and provisioning devices. For publishing private apps, follow the steps outlined in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9874937?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization).

To view all enrolled devices and perform various management tasks, you have a couple of options. You can build your dashboard by creating a management solution using the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management). Alternatively, if you prefer a third-party solution, you can integrate Android with an existing third-party EMM (Enterprise Mobility Management) provider. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/9419830?hl=en).